# Handling multiple file upload: When you push something to an array, when does the array update?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a file input that can handle multiple CSV files being uploaded at the same time. I loop through each file, run it through some data cleaning functions and then put it into a global array. My problem is that the array doesn't appear to update despite the fact that it appears updated when I `console.log` it.

Here is a recreation of my problem.

My HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="myInput" multiple>
```

And my code:

```
GLOBALARR = [];

$('#myInput').on('change',function(e) {
  files = e.target.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(files[i]);
    reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
      var csv = loadEvent.target.result;
      pushFileContentsToArray(csv);
    }
  }
  checkArray();
 });

function pushFileContentsToArray(csv) {
    GLOBALARR.push(csv);
}

function checkArray() {
  console.log(GLOBALARR);
  console.log(GLOBALARR.length);
}
```

Notice that the `console.log(GLOBALARR)` outputs the updated array, but the `console.log(GLOBALARR.length)` outputs 0 as the length. When I try to work with the elements in the array, I get undefined errors and whatnot, as if the array is still empty.

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onload` is an async operation, so you're calling `checkArray()` *before* the file has been read. To fix this, move the `checkArray()` call to just after the `pushFileContentsToArray()` call:

```
$('#myInput').on('change', function(e) {
  files = e.target.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(files[i]);
    reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
      var csv = loadEvent.target.result;
      pushFileContentsToArray(csv);
      checkArray();
    }
  }
});
```

Obviously this is going to perform this logic for every file you read. If you want to only call `checkArray()` once all files have been read you could create your own Promise and resolve it after `onload` has fired for all files, something like this:

```
$('#myInput').on('change', function(e) {
  let files = e.target.files;
  let filesRead = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(files[i]);
    reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
      var csv = loadEvent.target.result;
      pushFileContentsToArray(csv);

      if (++filesRead === files.length);
        checkArray();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you want to keep writing sequential code, you can take a look at async/await, so you could write code that is only executed after all files are loaded. `await Promise.all(...)`